# How can a multi-valued dimension be expressed in a star-schema given that it has 1-to-many relationship [Dim 1: many Fact]?

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence, star-schema

I am new to Data Warehouse practices and in the context of an academic exercise I would like to create a star-schema using a dataset in a chosen area of interest. So, my classmate and I chose a dataset of car accidents in a country during a year.

The **problem** is that in a lot of cases if not the most, there are more than one cars involved. So if I choose to have incidents of "accidents" as the Fact Table with "Driver", "Car", "Casualties", "Location", "Contitions" etc as Dimentions, how can these be transformed in a star-schema, when dimensions "Car", "Driver" and "Casualties" are multivalued? For example I can have 3 cars involved, 3 drivers and 7 casualties. Consider that the use of star-schema is mandatory.

Also, as far as I know, a Fact Table can most often have numeric values in measurements. Can it also has catecorical variables as measurements?

Comment: One way is to recognise that there is another dimension to this - a 'crash' dimension. So a crash with 5 cars gets five rows in the fact which all point at the same single dimension record (a new one is created per crash). This is one way to model a header-detail in a star schema without violating the star schema idea. You are legitimately modelling a 'crash' so it's OK to get it's own dimension with attributes around the crash. You could even say that the crash dimension could join off to another higher level fact at the crash level.

Comment: Another way to model it is to use a bridge table which is a construct that some (not all) reporting tools can utilise to stop double counting. http://www.kimballgroup.com/2012/02/design-tip-142-building-bridges/

Comment: Thanks  for your reply! So, if I understand correctly, you propose me to turn "Accidents" fact-table into a dimension-table and have as fact a table which is consisted only of dimensions' foreign keys?

Comment: It's one way to look at it, yes. Then your fact would be called something like participants. Its best to try a few things and experiment.

Comment: If this is the UK accidents data set, I'd advise sticking with the granularity as per the natural grain of the data (i.e., as provided in the download) and putting in a bridge table. It works, and will leave you with far less work to do in an academic excercise. Bridge tabels are not evil.

Answer (score 4):

A very important concept in dimensional modelling is that of the grain. Ralph Kimball (whose work you will run into again and again if you're learning about dimensional modelling) emphasizes that it's really important to model from the lowest possible grain up. This lets you slice and dice your data in as many ways as possible, summing up from the lowest to any higher granularities.

Quite often when you find one of these issues where everything seems to be many-to-many, the issue is actually that you've chosen the wrong grain for the fact table in question. With apologies to Nick.McDermaid (who has suggested this granularity change in comments), "participation of an individual in an accident" is a lower granularity than "accident," so lowering the granularity of the fact table to at least that level - and creating an Accident dimension - makes a lot of sense.

It's possible that's not the lowest granularity, though; for instance, if your data set tracks injuries, each participant might have multiple injuries. So the fact table grain might be better off as "injuries sustained during an accident," in that case - you would need a row in your Injury dimension that indicated "no injury," in case, to include those participants who were not injured. So the first thing you should do isn't decide what your fact table is, it's to sift through the data and try to figure out what your lowest granularity is; once you've done that, you should have a good handle on what your fact table will be modelled around, and which dimensions you need.

Dimensional modelling can be a bit of a tough nut to crack because there are multiple ways you can do things - and the most correct way often doesn't seem very obvious, especially if you're moving from a background where you're used to more normalised data structures. I'd suggest first and foremost try to model something using the most basic table types - i.e. try to avoid things like snowflaking, bridge tables, etc. - and see if you can come up with a solution that avoids those tricks. Very often this will lead to a better model (i.e. one which is simpler to navigate, has better query performance, and can be used to answer more questions).

Nick.McDermaid's advice to experiment and try different things is also solid, as it can help you to break yourself out of your initial assumptions. There are sometimes multiple potential designs - thinking them all through thoroughly can be necessary to decide which is best.

Answer (score 2):

I've had to model this very thing at my company.

Incident & Vehicle are at their own grains.  You'll need a FactIncident & a FactIncidentVehicle.  This allows you to associate attributes that are related to the Incident (Date, location, type) as well as attributes for each Vehicle in the Incident.

The Incident dimension is almost a degenerate dimension, containing just a few attributes with the IncidentID such as Police Report Number.

The Incident Vehicle dimension also has just a few attributes that are specific to the vehicle for this incident only, such as was the vehicle towed.  If your data allows for non-vehicle incidents (e.g. Trip & Fall), you'll need a 'No Vehicle' vehicle record in your dimension as well as the 'Unknown' vehicle.

Incident Vehicle Person is yet another grain to capture the relationship between the Person and Vehicle for this specific incident.  A junk dimension is useful for holding the flag(Y,N,Unk) questions, such as injured , cited, owner, driver, etc.

This approach works great, and allows an incident to have 0 to many vehicles and 1 to many people as well as allowing the same person and/or vehicle to be part of more than one incident (for fleet/employee records).

Answer (score 1):

The most common approach is to use a bridge table  http://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/multivalued-dimension-bridge-table/

Comment: Bridge tables are not necessarily the answer to this. The Kimball Group's take on bridge tables: "Similarly, if your design is riddled with bridge tables to capture many-valued dimension relationships, you need to go back to the drawing board. Chances are that you have an issue with the fact table’s granularity." (kimballgroup.com/2003/10/fistful-of-flaws)

Comment: Also we could quote the Kimball Group where they say that Bridge tables are exactly what you'd use in this situation. You typically have a choice to change the fact's natural grain or put in a bridge table. The bridge table is often the lesser of two evils, and indeed this seems the case here.

Comment: @Rich The Kimball Group certainly say they're an *option*, but they very much stress that they are not the only solution for these situations, and shouldn't be treated at the default solution in all cases. Nowhere do they say that you should choose them over other solutions, simply that you should consider all the options before deciding what is best for your specific scenario. Saying bridge tables are the solution with this little information is jumping to a conclusion way too early.

Comment: See http://www.kimballgroup.com/2014/05/design-tip-166-potential-bridge-table-detours/ and http://www.kimballgroup.com/2008/09/design-tip-105-snowflakes-outriggers-and-bridges/ for more info. Quote from the first: "Many-to-many relationships are typically best resolved in fact tables."

Comment: I don't think the selective quotes and downmark of that answer is useful- making it look like bridges are not the answer or to be avoided typically, when all the commenter did was point them to bridges as the most common approach (correctly). A bridge to solve this would not make the solution 'riddled with bridges', which is the Kimball Group's point at which you'd rethink your fact. Similarly other quotes from the articles you quote emphasise the benefits of bridges.

Comment: I admit that in this case my own knowledge of trying to work with this specific dataset does lead me to prefer a bridge to a fact grain so perhaps shouldn't have said 'indeed this seems the case here' without going into more detail on that.

Comment: @Rich - Why not write your own answer? An answer discussing why a bridge table is suitable in this case would be really useful here, especially if you know the data set. The current answer is just a link and a comment saying they're commonly used - it doesn't help anyone understand why it's a good solution *in this case*. I don't know the data set so could only give fairly generic advice. I have nothing against bridge tables - of course I use them - but they are often the generic answer here on SO, generally without any discussion of why they should be used. Your answer would be very valuable.

Comment: @Jo - Like I said, I shouldn't have said "indeed this seems the case here" without going into more detail on that, but my reply to Nick's comment on the question sums up my view, and I don't feel a separate answer is warranted.