# DataWarehouse - Fact Tables with different granularity / Dimension measures

Tags: database, database-design, ssas, data-warehouse

I've got data in the following format.

`RoadAccidents (pk_accidentIdentifier)` with relationship `1..*` to `Vehicles(fk_accidentIdentifier, ordinalNumber)` `->` natural PK (compound)  and surrogate, which is simply a `rowID`).

`ordinalumber` is just a number to iterate through vehicles that were involved in an accident.

```
--Sample Row
Accident001, 1, [list of attributes of a vehicle] -- 1st car involved in an inc
Accident001, 2, [list of attributes of a vehicle] -- 2nd car involved in an inc
```

`Vehicles` with `1..*` relationship with table `Casualties` which is connected in the same way as vehicles are with `RoadAccidents` Meaning:

`Casualties (Compound PK: (fk_vehicleID, casualtyOrdinalNumber)`

```
--Sample Row:
Vehicle001, 1, [list of attributes of a casualty] -- 1st casualty involved in inc
Vehicle001, 2, [list of attributes of a casualty] -- 2st casualty involved in inc
```

So the relationship looks as follows.

`RoadAccidents 1..* Vehicles 1..* Casualties`

In addition table `RoadAccidents` has already aggregated measures of `numberOfVehiclesInvolved` and `numberOfCasualties` .

There are 3(possibly more) approaches here for the `fact tables`

1. Two JOINS on `RoadAccident -> Vehicles -> Casualties` -> delete columns with aggregated numbers -> extract attributes to respective dimensions. Loose aggregated data -> have no meaningful measure -> create measures in SQL Server Data Tools.
2. Have 3 fact tables. `FactRoadAccident`, `FactVehiclesCollision`, `FactCasaultiesInvInCollision`

The problem I face: Fact tables should not be linked by foreign keys directly. Therefore, I can extract dimensions, such as.

```
DimRoadAccident *..1 DimRoadAccidentLocation 
DimRoadAccident` *..1 DimWeatherConditions
```

Fact table would look as follows:

`FactAccident` (`fk_DimRoadAccidentPK, measure_numberOfVehicles, measure_numberOfCasualties`).

With this approach. Fact tables for `Vehicles` and `Casualties` would be just a surrogate FK with the id of a `Vehicle` or `Casualty`. The only measures would be row counts, meaning - number of `Vehicles` or number of `Casualties`.

3. Keep only 1 fact table

`FactAccident` (`fk_DimRoadAccidentPK, measure_numberOfVehicles, measure_numberOfCasualties`).

Have dimensions linked `DimRoadAccident 1..* DimVehicle 1..* DimCasualty` and have hierarchies created in Data Tools and possibly create some new semi-additive measures on dimensions.

What appraoch would you suggest?

Comment: There's a very similar question here (possibly even based on the same data set?), my answer to that may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40774305/3964881. If you're still stuck I'll look to write a more detailed answer, as you have given more information here than the other post did. Think about the lowest granularity of data before deciding what your fact or dimension tables are. Once you understand the lowest granularity, the facts and dimensions become more obvious.

Comment: Thank you your answer Joe, it indeed seems to be the same data set. I referred to the grain of the data in my comment in the post below this.

Answer (score -1):

Use a Bridge table.  Bridge tables are used when you have a many-to-many relationship.  See here http://www.kimballgroup.com/2012/02/design-tip-142-building-bridges/

Comment: Bridge tables are not necessarily the answer to this. The Kimball Group's take on bridge tables: "Similarly, if your design is riddled with bridge tables to capture many-valued dimension relationships, you need to go back to the drawing board. Chances are that you have an issue with the fact table’s granularity." (http://www.kimballgroup.com/2003/10/fistful-of-flaws/)

Comment: This article of theirs also discusses the problems with and alternatives to bridge tables: http://www.kimballgroup.com/2014/05/design-tip-166-potential-bridge-table-detours/ - a major point made is that there is no one blanket solution to dealing with many-to-many situations. But they are very clear in all of their writing that you must first ensure you have the right grain - so that should be the first place to look, and things like bridge tables (which are outside of the standard model) should only be used when absolutely necessary.

Comment: Is this really considered many-to-many relationship? These are in my opinion pure 1..* in terms of the logical connection between the data. The only difference is that Accidents denormalized table (raw data) also holds already aggregated measures for no. of vehicles and no. of casualties.

Comment: I can have the grain in fact table brough to signle casualty / vehicle by having two columns that accept values {0,1} for casualty and vehicle and use them as measures. However, in this case it would be better to create semi-additive measures on dimensions in MS Data Tools.